# Convert a curl command into Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, curl, rabbitmq

I had a curl command which I converted using [this](https://jhawthorn.github.io/curl-to-ruby/).

This is the Ruby script:

```
 rabbitmqctl_url = CONFIG['rabbitmqctl']['url']
 rabbitmqctl_user = CONFIG['rabbitmqctl']['username']
 rabbitmqctl_password = CONFIG['rabbitmqctl']['password']
 uri = URI.parse("#{rabbitmqctl_url}/api/queues")
 request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
 request.basic_auth(rabbitmqctl_user, rabbitmqctl_password)
 req_options = { use_ssl: uri.scheme == 'https' }
 response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
    http.request(request)
 end
 puts response.body
```

This is the curl command:

```
curl -u  username:password  http:localhost 15672/api/queue
```

This code is very lengthy.

Comment: You might want to look into gems that wrap some or all of this stuff in a simpler API, like [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty). With that you should be able to get closer to the simplicity of the curl command. The basic Ruby API is (on purpose) very bare bones, and doesn't try to be clever about things